# What do the different colors of weather stations indicate on SkyVector?

Tags: weather, metar

In this particular map

[image]

from [SkyVector](http://skyvector.com), what are the meanings of the different colored circles, and for the different amounts of 'fill-in'?

- It's obvious by hovering over them, that they are weather stations, as the weather info will pop-up, but there doesn't seem to be anything (to my untrained eye) about the weather pop up that would indicate a need for the different colors.
- It's also obvious that the color doesn't indicate something permanent about the station, as last Friday, there were large swathes of different colors across the USA, while today almost everything is green.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Colors

At present<sup>1</sup>, [they mean *(image source)*](http://aviationweather.gov/taf/help?page=inter):

[image: Color codes]

For more details, please [see this description](http://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/description/page_no/4).

## Fill-ins

These are called sky/cloud coverage.

[image: Sky/Cloud Covers]
<sup>*[Image Source](http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/html/stationplot.shtml)*</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> [*From SkyVector:*](https://skyvector.com/comment/2820#comment-2820)

> The color is controversial because the FAA is making the NWS swap the
> colors for VFR and MVFR. When the new aviationweather.gov becomes the
> current aviationweather.gov, we'll change our colors to match.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. The SV link you posted wasn't particularly obvious from within SV...

Comment: You should add that the "fill in" is sky cover.